# Problem with responsive menu

Tags: navigation

Hi guys I am having a little problem with a responsive menu on a new build EE2 site.

This is the code:

```
    <div class="twelve columns alpha navigation">

        <!-- Default Superfish Nav (add/remove "light" class to toggle visual styling) -->
        <ul class="sf-menu light">
            <li><a href="/"><strong>Home</strong> <span>Get Started</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="{site_url}submit"><strong>Submit yours</strong> <span>Choose your 8!</span></a> 
                </li>
            <li><a href="{site_url}archives"><strong>Previous Castways</strong> <span>View the archives</span></a>  
                </li>
            <li><a href="{site_url}news"><strong>Latest News</strong> <span>Check out the news</span></a>   
                </li>

            <li><a href="{site_url}contact"><strong>Contact</strong> <span>Say Hello!</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /End Default Superfish Nav-->

        <!-- Responsive Nav - Displays when screen gets small enough -->
        <form id="responsive-nav" action="insert_action" method="post">
            <select>
                <option value="/">Home</option>
                <option value="{site_url}submit">Submit your 8!</option>
                <option value="{site_url}archives">Previous castaways</option>
                <option value="{site_url}news">The news</option>                        
                <option value="{site_url}contact">Contact</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <!-- /End Responsive Nav -->    
    </div>  <!--end of top menu-->
```

jQuery was loaded in the head now I put it in the bottom of the document, yet still nothing!
Can someone help? I have checked the paths and they all seem to be fine, well as you can see from the code, the path for the responsive menu is the same as the full size menu. Just can't figure out why it is not working.
I should add that when looking at the page source, the select menu and related links are generated, but they don't send you to the actual corresponding page!!

I am using the chosen.js plugin. Here is the code for this:

```
[http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/][1]
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it that you are seeing or not seeing?

Comment: I see the main menu, and at media query break point 767px the select menu appears and the main menu disappears. This is what is supposed to happen. However if I select any of the links in the Select menu, the links do not navigate to the page the menu item points to. Its very odd! I am using the skeleton framework to build the site, if that has any bearing.

Comment: You haven't shown us the JavaScript code for the select menu. We can't tell you what's wrong without seeing what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your efforts folks. I found out (through trial and error!)that the pluggin(chosen.js) had some sort of conflict with the latest version of jQuery. I reverted to an earlier version(1.6) and all is well with the world again.

Thanks again.